# How do you actually apply suffix arrays to any kind of text?

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, pattern-matching, suffix-array

I am reading about `Suffix Arrays` and the code to build one is simple. But all the resources I have found usually use a trivial example text, which usually is `banana`, to explain the concept.
So although the example text is trivial and the suffix array is presented (`a`,`ana`,`anana`,`banana`,`na`,`nana`) as I understand this can be applied to any kind of text.
But I don't understand how, as a text has spaces, new line characters, punctuantion marks etc.
So how does this apply to any kind of text?

Comment: What differentiates spaces, new line characters, punctuation marks, etc. from letters?

Comment: The most simplest case, you can replace the characters in the banana example with any other character and it will still apply. (Just that the terminating character needs to be unique and not appearing in the text).

Comment: @delnan:In programming languages we present each with different character e.g. `\n` for new line, `\t` for tab etc

Comment: @nhahtdh:So you are saying that any whitespace etc is also included in the suffixes?

Comment: @Cratylus That's just a notation for putting that character into a string literal without confusing the parser by literally inserting that character. (Also, that just covers some of the characters you're confused about.)

Comment: @delnan:But still, is a new line character part of a suffix?

Comment: @Cratylus: New line, space, whatever can be part of a suffix. Doesn't matter, as long as the line terminator is unique and does not appear in the text.

Comment: @nhahtdh:What is the difference with the line terminator and we must treat it specially?Also what is the difference of the line terminator and the new line character?

Comment: @Cratylus: Line terminator signifies the end of the string. It is not any specific character and can be any character not appearing in the text. (Line terminator is a concept in Suffix Tree/Array, while new line character is just the new line character).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a longer string your suffix array would look like so:

```
[01] banana split, yum!
[02] anana split, yum!
[03] nana split, yum!
[04] ana split, yum!
[05] na split, yum!
[06] a split, yum!
[07]  split, yum!
[08] split, yum!
[09] plit, yum!
[10] lit, yum!
[11] it, yum!
[12] t, yum!
[13] , yum!
[14]  yum!
[15] yum!
[16] um!
[17] m!
[18] !
```

You can then sort it in alphabetical order to find the longest repeated substring, a common use for suffix arrays.

I also remember doing something similar to find repeating patterns of words in a long text, and I used the space character as a separator, instead of going through each character:

```
[01] if it is true it is true
[02] it is true it is true
[03] is true it is true
[04] true it is true
[05] it is true
[06] is true
[07] true
```

Although this not a suffix array, once sorted alphabetically, one can find repeated patterns of words:

```
[01] if it is true it is true
[06] is true
[03] is true it is true
[05] it is true
[02] it is true it is true
[07] true
[04] true it is true
```

By comparing each line to the line above it, as long as the characters match, we find that 'is true' and 'it is true' are repeated patterns of words.

This method is inspired by a common DNA research problem called the longest repeated substring problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem

Of course, it does arise in other fields than genetic science.